Net/http posting nested parameters
I'm making a post request using the built-in net/http ruby library, and I need to update it to post nested parameters.
Currently, I get (from another object) the params in the following format:
{ :user => {:code=>"00004812", :valid_from=>"2024-01-01"} }

But If I try to post them as is, the endpoint receives them as a string:
Parameters: {"user"=>"{\"code\"=>\"00004812\", \"valid_from\"=>\"2024-01-01\"}"

And they are not correctly parsed.
I tried to change them manually as:
{"user[code]" => "00004812", "user[valid_from]" => "2024-01-01"}

And, with this format, they are received correctly:
 Parameters: {"user"=>{"code"=>"00004812", "valid_from"=>"2024-01-01"}}

Is there a way to make the change programmatically without changing how the data is received from the other object?
My code looks like:
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
response = http.request(request)


If set_form_data doesn't accept nested params, you could convert them to a query string (e.g. via ActiveSupport's to_query) and parse the string into a non-nested form, e.g. via CGI.parse(params.to_query) or Rack::Utils.parse_query(params.to_query). Or maybe set the request body directly via request.body = params.to_query.
